# Is there any P2P VPN solution that does not require port opening(forwarding)?

Tags: networking, vpn

The closest to a **VPN P2P-based** solution that I have found is [PeerVPN](http://www.peervpn.net/): really easy to install, but it needs to *open one port* (7000 TCP by default) on one of the computers (also known as `node`) that runs it.

I would like to prepare some Linux devices to automatically connect to any **specific VPN network**, for example by using some cron task, in order to **find them remotely wherever** they are. I have no access to the router(s), so **I can not open ports**.

The optimal solution would be some tool like:

```
# p2pvpn --connect --network MyNetworkName
$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciónHW 00:23:54:7f:f2:4f
          Direc. inet:192.168.11.113  Difus.:192.168.11.255 Másc:255.255.255.0
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  direcciónHW 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          Direc. inet:10.8.0.6  P-t-P:10.8.0.5  Másc:255.255.255.255
```

Note the `tun0` newly created **virtual interface**.
 
Is there anything like this?

*Command-line* solutions preferred.
*Multi-platform* solutions preferred.

Additional points:
- Similar solutions (still require port(s) opening) are programs like **OpenVPN** (nearly a headache to setup, but working great).

Answer (score 1):

This *should* be possible if you use UDP and port numbers for both source and destination, although I haven't tried it. For example:

- A sends packets to B from port 1194 to port 1194
- B sends packets to A from port 1194 to port 1194
- B's firewall allows the packets from A because it thinks they are in reply to the packets that B sent.
- A's firewall allows the packets from B because it thinks they are in reply to the packets that A sent.

Many, but not all, firewalls, will allow this kind of UDP hole punching. But it will not work with TCP because firewalls track the state of TCP connections more closely and you cannot fool them as easily. That means that the PeerVPN software you mentioned is out because you mentioned it uses TCP. But OpenVPN should work, it uses UDP by default (and its documentation mentions how TCP for a VPN is not a good idea, for unrelated reasons). For OpenVPN, the option to use a fixed local port number is `--lport`.

You can also try using fixed source and destination ports, but a different port on each side.

Scenarios where there is a double NAT on one or both sides, or NATs that do not attempt to preserve source ports, or firewalls that are stricter than usual, will foil UDP hole punching.

Or you could use IPv6 instead of IPv4. The sheer number of available IPv6 addresses obviates the need for NAT and all its annoyances!